# How do I use a function to set the default search to be for products only?

Tags: wordpress

I need to set the search that's part of the theme, to search for Products only.  At the moment it searches the whole platform.

It's not a custom form I need just the ability to change the default search operation.  So rather than going to /s?green, it includes the 'product' code in the URL so it searches only for products.

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts' );
function custom_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
    if ( is_search() ) {
        $query->set('post_type', 'product');
    }

    return $query;
}
```

We just want it to show products in their product tiles, rather that blog results.

Answer (score 0):

If you only will ever be searching the `product` post type on your site, you can create your own `searchform.php` template to include this hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product" />
```

You can place that anywhere within the `form` HTML markup. Below is the what WP outputs by default if there is no `searchform.php` file and you're using the HTML5 form support.

```
<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product"/>
    <label>
        <span class="screen-reader-text"><?php _e( 'Search for:', 'label' ); ?></span>
        <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Search &hellip;', 'placeholder' ); ?>" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" name="s"/>
    </label>
    <input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Search', 'submit button' ); ?>"/>
</form>
```

You can add the above code to your own `searchform.php` and add that to the root of your THEME directory.

Comment: It seems to have multiple search forms.  It works in one but not in all.

Not on this one, and based on the URL result, this is the one that needs it.

<form class="grve-search" method="get" action="https://......//" > <button type="submit" class="grve-search-btn grve-custom-btn grve-text-primary-1"><i class="grve-icon-search"></i></button> <input type="text" class="grve-search-textfield grve-h1" value="" name="s" placeholder="Search for ..." autocomplete="off"/></form>

Comment: What theme are you using?

Comment: It's ok, we found the solution.  It was within the theme's functions.  We simple took out the function, edited the form it uses, and placed it in the child theme.

Answer (score 0):

It was within the functions file in the root theme area.  We were directed to it, them took it out, placed it in child theme, edited the Form tag in the code, and it worked.